# Python- redirect the input/output of subprocess

Tags: python, io, subprocess

I have three folders: 
(1) contains the source code 
(2) contains binary files 
(3) aimed to contain the output of executing source code

using the `subprocess`, I want to execute the source code from (1), that reads all binary files in (2), and puts the results (in my case `.csv` files) in (3)

so far I succeeded in only reading the files from (2), however they are processed properly and not couldn't direct the output to (3).

The code I wrote for this is the following:

```py
for path in filesList:
    if 'name' in path and not os.path.splitext(path)[1]:    
        proc = subprocess.Popen([code, path, "input arguments"],shell=True)
```

How can control the input/output folders of my code using `subprocess` or any other way?

Comment: `Popen` opens a separate program as a subprocess. The output is typically controlled by this opened program. Thus, you need to make this program write the files at the correct location. Or, to `stdout`, whereafter your main program can save the output to a file.

Comment: @JohanL Thank you for your comment. I changed my program to write to the desired directory. 
However, I couldn't get what do you mean exactly by: `to stdout, whereafter your main program can save the output to a file`

Comment: If your subprocess generates output to `stdout` it is possible for the main process to read the output and to further process it, or store it to a file. That is the possibility I was talking about.